Is Google Picker API affected with deprecation of client side javascript libraries?
I am looking to implement Google Picker modal into my product. However, while I was going through the documentation, I came across a page which mentions that the JS libraries are being deprecated.
Here's an article.
Since google's official documentation for picker shows the usage of these deprecated libraries, I am confused whether to use the code or not - given they didn't explicitly mentioned on picker documentation about deprecation.
However, since it's using below two libraries, it seems it wouldn't be ideal to follow the picker doc.
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="onApiLoad()"></script>  <script async defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="gisLoaded()"></script>
Please help me understand what alternative approach I can use to implement the picker?
I tried the code from picker documentation and it works fine, however I am concerned if it is ideal to use it.

The google's official documentation for picker is up-to-dated and using the new Google Identity Services library for authorization. That actually follows the approach suggested in the blog post. In short, you should follow the official documentation.

Thanks. Is this officially mentioned anywhere that documentation code uses new Google Identity Service library for authorization? If yes, please help to provide the source link.

This page https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis covers extensively on using GAPI library and GIS library. In particular, this section https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis#implicit_flow_examples is most applicable in your case.
